# Generate Access Report

Tags: .net, vba, ms-access

I am creating reports in MS Access. For now, every time I need to generate a report, I need to go to Access and run the report. Then, export it as PDF or send it over the email. I wonder if there is a way to automate this process. For example, I would like to schedule running the report at 6 am in the morning, and deliver it by email without manually doing them myself.

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks very much!

Comment: why the .net tag here ?

Comment: [See this documentation?](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-(help/distribute-a-report-electronically-HA010206320.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can:

1. Write an Access macro that saves the report to pdf then closes the app
2. make a batch file to start Access opening myDb and the [startup switch](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209207) to start your macro ( `/x myMacro`).
3. create a windows job that runs the batch file the desired interval